# How to assign default value to a foreign key using fluent api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I created two models using fluent api in my dbcontext(ToDo, Category) what I want to achieve is that whenever I create a new ToDo object, the default value for CategoryId is specified as an id for the 'Default' category that I successfully created previously, I still need that relationship to be non optional to be able to use cascade deletion, but so that if not specified in a request body, the value of categoryid always assigns to 1.

The issue I'm having now is that when not specifying the categoryid simply gets a null value.
Here are the request and the respond that followed it:
POST to api/todos

```
{
    "Context":"234234"
    
}




{
    "id": 2,
    "context": "234234",
    "done": false,
    "dueDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "category": null
}
```

```
  public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ToDo> todos { get; set; }

        public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.Entity<ToDo>().ToTable("TODO");
            builder.Entity<ToDo>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
            builder.Entity<ToDo>().Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
            builder.Entity<ToDo>().Property(p => p.Context).HasMaxLength(50);
            builder.Entity<ToDo>().Property(p => p.Done);
            builder.Entity<ToDo>().Property(p => p.DueDate);
            builder.Entity<ToDo>().Property(p => p.CategoryId).HasDefaultValue(1);

            builder.Entity<Category>().ToTable("CATEGORIES");
            builder.Entity<Category>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
            builder.Entity<Category>().Property(p => p.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();//.HasValueGenerator<InMemoryIntegerValueGenerator<int>>();
            builder.Entity<Category>().Property(p => p.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(30);
            builder.Entity<Category>().HasMany(p => p.ToDoS).WithOne(p => p.Category).HasForeignKey(p => p.CategoryId);

            builder.Entity<Category>().HasData(
      new
      {
          Id = 1,
          Name = "Default"

      }

  );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement it on old data? Im not sure if it will have any effect but try putting the ToDo entity builder after you declare that you have a data in category. Are you making the migration to this?

Comment: nope, Im using inmemorydb so the data gets wiped out everytime i restart the app, putting ToDo after data seeding didn't help

Comment: Your problem with inmemorydb is that it doesnt check for constains, so maybe you dont really have that data. Try switching it up to an SQL Lite or Sql and see if it throws an error. If it does then are you sure u made the corresponding migration?

Comment: I can confirm your code works with SQLite but not with InMemory.

Comment: [Default values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#default-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the comments and searching the web I can clearly say that the problem really was the usage of inmemorydb , cause after switching to localdb everything works just fine.